# How to send multiple files with post request a API in Angular 4

Tags: angular, web-services, typescript, http, file-upload

I want to append multiple files to API, it works for me to send just one file . 
I catch the all files and console.log(array) gives me the all files but I couldn't send all files to API, it just sends one file.

My HTML component

```
<input type="file" name="howeworkfile[]"  ngModel 
#howeworkfile="ngModel" multiple="multiple"  
(change)="getFile($event)" 
>
```

My component TS

```
getFile(event) {
let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
if (fileList.length > 0) {
  console.log(fileList);
  let file: File = fileList[0];
  let formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('howeworkfile[]', file);
 formData.append('class_id', 7);
 formData.append('subject_id', 1);
 formData.append('school_id', 77);
 formData.append('name', 'sd');
 formData.append('description', 'sgerhgdf');
 formData.append('score', '2');
 formData.append('weight', 200);
 formData.append('type', 12);
 formData.append('deadline', '2018-02-13');
    this._http.post(this.url, formData)
  .subscribe(respo => {
    console.log(respo);
    // console.log(data.file);
  }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
 }
}}
```

Comment: Put it in a foreach loop.

Comment: put what in foreach loop ?

Comment: formData. Use the parameter in the post. [Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 2):

It should be like

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" (change)="getFile($event)">

...

getFile(event) {
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    for (const file of fileList) {
        formData.append('some name', file, file.name) // file.name is optional
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: The name 'some name' must be different for each file ; increment it with a variable for instance.